# Redirecting from /login to / for authenticated users

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-java-config

We have a Spring Security app that mostly just handles authentication via a Thymeleaf page before passing the user to an Angular application. Currently if a user has already logged in tries going to /login, it takes them to the login page to be filled out - if they go to just / then they'll be properly redirected to our dashboard/homepage. We just want to be able to redirect /login to / for authenticated users.

Here's the HttpSecurity configuration we're using that I'm guessing should only require a simple modification to achieve this goal:

```
@Override
public void configure( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception
{
    // @formatter:off
    http
            .cors()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedHandler( accessDeniedHandler() )
            .authenticationEntryPoint( new RestAuthenticationEntryPoint() )
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers( "/login" ).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage( "/login" )
            .failureHandler( internalAuthFailureHandler )
            .successHandler( internalAuthSuccessHandler )
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl( "/logout" )
            .logoutSuccessUrl( "/login?logout" )
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository( CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse() );
    // @formatter:on
}
```

I tried using .not().authenticated() for the /login page, but couldn't figure that out and I don't understand what documentation is supposed to help with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the filter that generates the login page is higher than the filter that processes the HttpSecurity matchers, hence why using `.not().authenticated()` or other conventional methods did not work for you.

First, I created a custom filter class, I named it LoginPageFilter:

```
class LoginPageFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() != null
              && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().isAuthenticated()
              && ((HttpServletRequest)request).getRequestURI().equals("/login")) {
            System.out.println("user is authenticated but trying to access login page, redirecting to /");
            ((HttpServletResponse)response).sendRedirect("/");
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

The above will check if the current user is authenticated and if the current path is `/login`.

If he is, then it will redirect him to `/`. Otherwise, continue going through the filter chain.

After, you need to add the filter to the existing filter chain, but you can't add it anywhere. It has to be after the authentication has been resolved by the session id (otherwise, `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` would always return null) and it has to be before the existing filter than permits access to the login page.

The best candidate is before `DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter`, which is the filter generating the login page.

To add the custom filter at that position, you need to add this at the top of your `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method:

```
http.addFilterBefore(new LoginPageFilter(), DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.class);
```

In your example, it would look like the following:

```
@Override
public void configure( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception
{
    http.addFilterBefore(new LoginPageFilter(), DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.class);
    // @formatter:off
    http
            .cors()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedHandler( accessDeniedHandler() )
            .authenticationEntryPoint( new RestAuthenticationEntryPoint() )
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers( "/login" ).permitAll()
            // ...
    // @formatter:on
}
```

I've uploaded my complete class in case you need to have a closer look at it:

https://gist.github.com/TwinProduction/5e2e320f5f87c009c330828c3e34a6dc

Good luck!

### Update

At @dur's suggestion, I replaced `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` for `DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter`, which is much more appropriate candidate.

Comment: This works perfectly! I'm trying to understand how this works though.  

You mentioned that the filter responsible for the login page is higher than the one for HttpSecurity matchers. I'm guessing you're referring to the Spring Security Filter Chain? Where would those two steps take place? SecurityContexPersistenceFilter for the login page and the authentication processing mechanisms (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter, CasAuthenticationFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter, etc.) for HttpSecurity matchers?

Comment: What does it mean that the filter generates the login page (DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter)?  

The line breaks are a lie! (can I add formatting here?...)

Comment: If you add `logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG` to your `application.properties`, you can see every steps taken when you make a request to a page. If one of the filter executes something like response.sendRedirect(...), then it will disrupt the flow of the filter chain, meaning that the next filters won't be executed. For `DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter`, it automatically generates the login form if the current page is `/login`. Because that filter is before the filter that checks if the user can access it or not, the form is generated regardless. The solution provided prevents that.

Comment: Did the same and it works fine. Important parts to have : `.antMatchers("/login*").not().authenticated()` and `.formLogin().permitAll()`, otherwise I as having a error like _Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Unable to handle the Spring Security Exception because the response is already committed.] with root cause ..._

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution, using the idea in the accepted answer but with XML config (in case anyone needs this and they're using XML). The accepted answer is missing else { } on the doFilter.
This is tested and working:

spring-security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<b:beans xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
    https://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <http
        entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint">



        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll"/>       
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" requires-channel="https"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>


        <!-- DEFINE FILTER POSITION -->
        <custom-filter ref="loginPageFilter" before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>


    </http>


    <!-- DEFINE FILTER -->
    <b:bean id="loginPageFilter" class="com.common.filter.LoginPageFilter"/>


    <b:bean id="authenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <b:constructor-arg name="loginFormUrl" value="/login"/>
    </b:bean>
</b:beans>
```

LoginPageFilter.java

```
public class LoginPageFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() != null
              && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().isAuthenticated()
              && ((HttpServletRequest)request).getRequestURI().equals("/login")) {

            ((HttpServletResponse)response).sendRedirect("/");
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }   
}
```